# Google maps Javascript API usage statistics no show

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

I am currently using the google [Geocoder service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Geocoder) from the Google Maps JavaScript API in a few applications.

For months I was receiving usage statistics in my API manager, but for the last 2 months it has gone dark [usage screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DC4eI.jpg).

I know that the service is still working, and I know that we are receiving around 500 -1000 geocoding requests per day across 3 apps... But as we add geocoding functionality to more maps, or if we hit a peak day (we have one or two per year) I am worried that I will come close to my 25,000/day limit.

Anyone know why I lost my usage stats? I have tried the "send feedback" form... This error did occur around the time that I moved my API key from my personal gmail account to our organizations account.

Comment: Hi - I haven't been able to -- The API still works, but still shows now statistics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Maps Usage Reports is only for the customers with the new version of the Google Maps APIs Premium Plan which became available last January 2016.

To determine whether you have a previous license: In the Google CLoud Support Portal, click Maps: Usage Report on the left. If the ID at the top of the report is the following format, you have the new Premium Plan:
gme-[company] & proj-[number] ([type])
Otherwise, you have a previous license.

See Maps APIs for Work Licenses guide: https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/previous-licenses/

Answer (score 0):

Based on  [Official Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/usage-limits#maps-javascript-api-services-client-side), you have daily free quota of 100,000 requests per 24 hours for Geocoding. Additional requests applied against the annual purchase of Maps API Credits. Take note that if you use Premium Plan, your application consumes quota at different rates, depending on the APIs it requests.

The error occurred due to API key moved to different account. Each Google API key is unique associated with a specific signing certificate. You might be able to get a new API key. Check you Developer Console and set the "*Account Owner"* and "*Users*"

If you have encountered conflicting accounts, you may check this link: https://support.google.com/a/answer/185186?hl=en

Comment: We are on the standard/free plan for 25k. I see that my personal account key and the organization account key seem to be linked, they are the same and therefore not unique.. For the first couple of days after switching accounts, before it went dark, my usage statistics were goofy/overlapping/duplicated, so this makes some sense. I will delete my personal account and regenerate the key on the organization during off-peak hours, and check this answer up if that does the trick.